# how to access values of one matrix coresponding to the matrix of other values

Tags: matlab

`data=[ 20 25 30 35 40];` and a vector `u` of specific values for my data vector, where is `u=[0.5 0.8 1];` and I want to access values from vector `u` 
for each element of data vector to calculate values of `a` and `c` where

```
b=data+u  
c=data.*u
```

I wrote this program in MATLAB

```
data=[ 20 25 30 35 40];
u=[0.5 0.8 1];
i=0;
if (data(i+1)<=25)
    u=0.5;
elseif (data(i+1)>25 || data(i+1)<35)
    u=0.8;
else (data(i+1)>35)
    u=1;
end
b=data+u
c=data.*u
```

but i did not find right answer can  u help me to write it properly?

Comment: Please mention what is wrong with your current code. Also try to use the matlab debugger to understand the problem better.

Comment: sorry to say but i am first time working with matlab thats why dont know too much about dealing with error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data=[ 20 25 30 35 40];
u=[0.5 0.8 1];

for i = 1:length(data)
    if (data(i)<=25)
        u_idx=1
    elseif (data(i)>25 & data(i)<=35)
        u_idx=2;
    else (data(i)>35)
        u_idx=3;
    end

    b(i)=data(i)+u(u_idx);
    c(i)=data(i).*u(u_idx);

end
```